# Multi-threading looping a synchronous ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading

I have implemented an application to FTP files from a server machine to a client one

```
for(String sourceFolder : foldersPaths){
  transferFolder(channelSftp,SFTPWORKINGDIR+sourceFolder,
                          DESWORKINGDIR+sourceFolder.replace("/","\\"));
}
```

this piece of code iterates over an ArrayList of Strings having source path for every file I need to transfer. I was thinking about making use of the bandwidth and initiate several transfers for different files at the same time.

How can I create different threads executing the "transferFolder" method concurrently. Can it be safe so that the same item is not looped twice in different threads.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you modifying in this method? If two threads are modifying some global array on every iteration of this loop, then no, you can't synchronize it very easily. However, you can use a synchronized array if you don't mind each thread independently modifying the array randomly for the duration of each for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Set<String> submitted = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); // how many threads to work with it

    for(final String sourceFolder : foldersPaths){
        if(! submitted.contains(sourceFolder)) {
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    transferFolder(...); // your method invoked here
                }
            };
            if (submitted.add(sourceFolder)) {
                executorService.submit(runnable);
            }
        }
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have an [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) to hold your URI's, and have it safely shared across Threads in a pool to [execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not looping but mutation. If your `List` is immutable you can have as much `Thread`s reading from it as you want.

If you want to remove/add from/to this `List` however you need to do some synchornization **or** you have to use a concurrent data structure. The latter is the one I recommend. For your case a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` may do the trick.

If you need a queue-like data structure you can use for example the `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1 :

A queue data structure would be the most appropriate for this operation. Acquire a lock when you are fetching a file from the Queue and then release the lock once you are done. The same object should be used for granting access to the queue across all the threads.

```
while(!queue.isEmpty())
{
  synchronized(lockingObject)   /// Get the lock for mutual access to Queue
  {
     String file = queue.dequeue();
  }
 // lock is released
}
```

Comment: Java has the `concurrent` packages for a reason. I think manual synchronization is not necessary here.

Comment: Yes ConcurrentLinkedQueue would best serve the purpose. However the reason why i showed manual sync was to make the OP aware of the how such things work in a Multithreaded scenario